# Python generator with external break condition

Tags: python, generator

I need to iterate over ascending sequences x of n (= 5, f.i.) integers, finding all sequences for which a function f(*x) returns True.

Assume that if f_n(*y) is False for a particular y, then f_n(*z) id False for any z with z_i >= y_i. So f_n is monotonic in all its arguments.

This kind of generator function could be used in the following way to determine all ascending sequences of integers that have a sum of squares < 100

```
for sequence in generate_sequences(5):
   if sum_squares_is_at_least(sequence, 100):
       # some code to trigger the breaking of the generator loop
   else:
       print sequence
```

Clarification:
The problem here is that we need to iterate of n elements individually. Initially, we iterate [1,1,1,1,1] to [1,1,1,1,x], and then we have to continue with [1,1,1,2,2] to [1,1,1,2,y], eventually ending with [a,b,c,d,e]. It seems that the generator should look something like this, but needs some code to break out of the for and/or while loops if necessary (determined externally):

```
def generate_sequences(length, minimum = 1):
    if length == []:
        yield []

    else: 
        element = minimum
        while True:

            for sequence in generate_sequences(length - 1, element):
                yield element + [sequence]

            element += 1
```

Example:
For n = 3, and sum of squares no larger than 20, the following sequences would be generated:
[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]

Note that in the general case, I cannot use the information that 4 is the upper bound for each element. This would also seriously impact the running time for larger examples.

Comment: Why not just use `break`?

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.takewhile`?

Comment: You should confess, that your current description of the problem is rather confusing. A couple of examples if input and expected output might be very useful.

Comment: it's a nice Project-Euler-style problem!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)?

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> def gen():  #infinite generator
...    i=0
...    while True:
...       yield range(i,i+5)
...       i = i+1
... 
>>> [ x for x in takewhile( lambda x:sum(x)<20, gen() ) ]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>>
```

Comment: @user480441 -- What would it generate?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it

it.takewhile(lambda x: sum_squares_is_at_least(x, 100), generate_sequences(5))
```

If you are now sure about the **5** in the `generate_sequences`, then just let it `yield` the numbers as long as it is called:

```
def generate_sequences():
    i = 0 # or anything
    while True:
        yield [i, i] # or anything
        i = i + 1 # or anything
```

Then use it this way:

```
it.takewhile(lambda x: sum_squares_is_at_least(x, 100), generate_sequences())
```

Comment: generate_sequences is what I am trying to achieve. Also, i don't know the upper bounds for individual elements, so I wouldn't know when to start iterating over the next element.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with recursion by starting with a given list then appending another number (with logic to prevent going over sum of squares target)

```python
def makegen(N): #make a generator with max sumSquares: N
    def gen(l=[]): #empty list is valid with sum == 0
        yield l
        if l:
            i = l[-1] #keep it sorted to only include combinations not permutations
        else:
            i = 1 #only first iteration
        sumsquare = sum(x*x for x in l) #find out how much more we can add
        while sumsquare + i*i < N: #increase the appended number until we exceed target
            for x in gen(l+[i]): #recurse with appended list
                yield x
            i += 1
    return gen
```

calling our generator generator (tee hee :D) in the following fashion allows us to have any maximum sum of squares we desire

```
for x in makegen(26)():
    print x
```

Comment: just my take on kind of a fun problem of generator iteration